# multiple socket connections python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I know this question has been already answered, but please dont mark it as duplicate until you read my case. I have a socket server and client, I want to command all devices at once without threading, because that could potentially break my server by flooding or something like that, is it possble to do that with:

```
devices=10 #my device count
s.listen(devices) 
#and then
while True:
   conn, addr = s.accept()
   conn.send(command.encode())
```

so would it send the command to all connected devices?

Comment: Did you want to ‘command all devices‘ that are currently connected?

Comment: yeah, basically

Comment: So just iterate through the collection of sockets that the server has accepted.

Comment: um can you provide a sample code in answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over your connections:

```
def command_all(connections, command):
    for conn in connections:
        conn.send(command.encode())
```